# AS3 Save or create folder file on the server

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a code that generates a file, today it downloads the file and I wish that this file is created on the server and not downloaded to the machine's User.

```
var ref:FileReference = new FileReference();
ref.browse([new FileFilter('Saved files', '*.save')]);
```

can anyone help me as I change the code to create the file on the server and not sava it on the remote computer download

Comment: The code you posted does nothing but let the user choose a file on their computer. It neither uploads or downloads anything. Can you clarify what you want it to do? Upload the file to a server?

Comment: I have a program in AS3 that generates a file, that file today the User can down it, I want to change the code so that the program create the file on the server and not download option

Comment: you need a server side application to handle uploaded file to server , use Java  or PHP to save uploaded stream on your server

Comment: Your snippet will do nothing for yóur plan. Why the user should choose a file on his own local maschine, if you want to create a file on the server? Are you using Air or Flash? What you could do in Flash is to build your file like you do it now, let select the user that file and upload it using the `FIleReference.upload()`method. // To make it quite in background without useraction you must use a URLLoader, send the RAW-data to a php-file on your server, which can generate and save it as the filetype you need

Comment: 'To create and modifying files' you have to go with File class. And its only available in AIR only.

Comment: What do you mean it "generates a file"? You probably just need to send data to a server via `URLLoader` and use a server-side script to save it to a file, like @JileniBouguima said.

Comment: For this to be properly answered, you need to share what kind of webserver you are using.    The answer will be very dependent on the server side language.  .NET or PHP or Java etc.